# Groovy to get node values from XML in SoapUI response

Tags: xml, groovy, soapui, xmlslurper

I try to get node values from `XML` response in a `Groovy` script in `SoapUI`. XML file sample:

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <soap:Body>
      <ns2:validateSignatureResponse xmlns:ns2="http://validation.dss.esig.europa.eu/" xmlns:ns3="http://dss.esig.europa.eu/validation/diagnostic" xmlns:ns4="http://dss.esig.europa.eu/validation/simple-report" xmlns:ns5="http://dss.esig.europa.eu/validation/detailed-report">
         <WSReportsDTO>
            <ns3:diagnosticData>
               <ns3:DocumentName>testSigned.pdf</ns3:DocumentName>
               <ns3:ValidationDate>2019-08-08T09:54:34</ns3:ValidationDate>
               <ns3:Signatures>
                  <ns3:Signature Id="id-547ee2a04f4daf63g7e8g784b9920188719ca1f589e514egeg4573c1d1e0ea697b">
                     <ns3:SignatureFilename>testSigned.pdf</ns3:SignatureFilename>
                     <ns3:DateTime>2017-07-05T14:34:34</ns3:DateTime>
                     <ns3:SignatureFormat>PAdES-BASELINE-T</ns3:SignatureFormat>
                     <ns3:StructuralValidation>
                        <ns3:Valid>true</ns3:Valid>
                     </ns3:StructuralValidation>
```

I tried to use `XmlSlurper`, as shown below:

```
def slurped = new XmlSlurper().parseText(response);
def status = ${slurped.'ns3:diagnosticData'.'ns3:Signatures'.'ns3:StructuralValidation'.'ns3:Valid'};
```

I got error message:

> groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method:
>   Script23.$() is applicable for argument types:
>   (Script23$_run_closure1) values: [Script23$_run_closure1@1e6835]
>   Possible solutions: is(java.lang.Object), run(), run(), any(),
>   use([Ljava.lang.Object;), any(groovy.lang.Closure) error at line: 13

After that I tried with this code and didn't get any error message, but property value is empty after execution.

```
def slurped = new XmlSlurper().parseText(response);
def indication = slurped.diagnosticData.Signatures.StructuralValidation.Valid;
```

I tried the same also in different form:

```
def code = new XmlSlurper().parseText(xml)
                           .Body
                           .validateSignatureResponse
                           .WSReportsDTO
                           .diagnosticData
                           .Signatures
                           .Signature
                           .StructuralValidation
                           .Valid
                           .text()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use GPath, Groovy's equivalent of XPath, to go straight to your element rather than navigating down the hierarchy:

```
def response = '''
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <soap:Body>
        <ns2:validateSignatureResponse xmlns:ns2="http://validation.dss.esig.europa.eu/" xmlns:ns3="http://dss.esig.europa.eu/validation/diagnostic" xmlns:ns4="http://dss.esig.europa.eu/validation/simple-report" xmlns:ns5="http://dss.esig.europa.eu/validation/detailed-report">
            <WSReportsDTO>
                <ns3:diagnosticData>
                    <ns3:DocumentName>testSigned.pdf</ns3:DocumentName>
                    <ns3:ValidationDate>2019-08-08T09:54:34</ns3:ValidationDate>
                    <ns3:Signatures>
                        <ns3:Signature Id="id-547ee2a04f4daf63g7e8g784b9920188719ca1f589e514egeg4573c1d1e0ea697b">
                            <ns3:SignatureFilename>testSigned.pdf</ns3:SignatureFilename>
                            <ns3:DateTime>2017-07-05T14:34:34</ns3:DateTime>
                            <ns3:SignatureFormat>PAdES-BASELINE-T</ns3:SignatureFormat>
                            <ns3:StructuralValidation>
                                <ns3:Valid>true</ns3:Valid>
                            </ns3:StructuralValidation>
                        </ns3:Signature>
                    </ns3:Signatures>
                </ns3:diagnosticData>
            </WSReportsDTO>
        </ns2:validateSignatureResponse>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
'''

def parsedXML = new XmlSlurper().parseText(response)
def status = parsedXML.'**'.findAll { it.name() == 'Valid' }
println(status)
```

See [Groovy Goodness: Navigating with GPath](https://mrhaki.blogspot.com/2009/10/groovy-goodness-navigating-with-gpath.html) for a gentle introduction.